# Weak formulation for heat and wave equation

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider the IVP for heat equation given by
$$
\begin{cases}
u_t-\Delta u =0 & (x,t) \in \mathbb{R}^d \times (0,\infty)\\
u(x,0)=u_0(x) &  x\in \mathbb{R}^d
\end{cases}
$$
We can define the weak formulations in two ways:

The standard weak formulation of the above IVP (see for example the book Partial Differential Equations by L.C. Evans) is to look for  $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+;H^1(\mathbb{R}^d))$ with $u'\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^+,H^{-1}(\mathbb{R}^d))$ satisfying

\begin{eqnarray}
\langle u',v\rangle - \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d}  \sum\limits_{i=1}^du_{x_i}v_{x_i} dx = 0. \qquad \text{ for all }v\in H^1_0(\mathbb{R}^d) \label{1}\tag{1} 
\end{eqnarray}

On the other hand, one can also define the weak formulation as $u\in C([0,\infty);L^2(\mathbb{R}^d))$ satisfying
\begin{eqnarray}
\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^d\times \mathbb{R}^+}(u \phi_t +u \Delta \phi)dx dt=0 \qquad \text{for all } \phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d \times \mathbb{R}^+) \label{2}\tag{2}
\end{eqnarray}

**Why the formulation \eqref{1} is preferred over \eqref{2}? 

The same question is applicable for the IVPs for wave equations as well.**

P.S.: I understand that \eqref{2} cannot be used for initial boundary value problems (IBVP) as the trace of $L^2$ functions do not exist in general. However, for IVPs we do not ned the existence of such traces traces so \eqref{2} seems more natural. Moreover, since the PDE is Parabolic, anyways solutions can be shown to be sufficiently smooth.

Comment: Formulation (2) is a special case of interpreting the equation when $u$ is a distribution. I would think that formulation (1) only makes sense if $u \in C^1([0, \infty), V)$, where $V$ is a suitable Banach space of functions. Formulation 1 says that the usual derivative $u_t(t) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{u(t + h) - u(t)}{h} \in V$ is equal to the distribution $\Delta u(t)$. See chapter 6 of Taylor's PDE book for exposition on formulation 1. Advantage of formulation 1 is that $u_t$ is an actual Frechet derivative, not a weak derivative.